# How to install printer Brother HL-6180DW

Tags: printing, 15.04, brother

I tried with the existing tools but it didn't work.

Moreover, this printer is not on the list of printers to be selected.
Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[download the brother Linux installer](http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006893/linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz)

Once download is finished then extract this compressed file.

now from you terminal give execution permission to the installed file

```
chmod +x /path-to-extracted-dir/linux-brprinter-installer*
```

Now run the script:

```
sudo ./linux-brprinter-installer*
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much for your help.